# Center a CSS Menu/Drop Down Menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, centering

I am using this template on my website: http://www.css3templates.co.uk/templates/CSS3_gallery_grey/index.html 
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uPw85/

**What I need help with:**
1) Center the menu on the page, as you can see on the link it's left aligned.
2) Still keep the text in the drop down menus aligned to the left (just as in the link above).

I've searched this page and on Google a lot before asking for help and *none* of the results have worked for me.  I've tried just about every tip I've found but the menu still won't be centered for me, the only thing that happens is that the text in the drop down menu is centered but I want to keep it to the left.

I've tried with multiple variations of these in different places (nav, menu, li, ul) in the CSS but with no luck:

```
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;,
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: auto;
```

**EDIT 2/10, 1 PM EST**: I appreciate you guys trying to help but so far none of the answers you've given has helped.

Comment: If you specify a width to your ul, ex. 700px and add margin-left and margin-right: auto it will center-align

Comment: I changed my ul to:
ul { 
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

Changing the width did nothing, it's still aligned to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul.sf-menu {
text-align: center;
}

ul.sf-menu li {
display: inline-block;
}

ul.sf-menu li a {
display: block;
}

ul.sf-menu ul {
text-align: left;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've edited the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uPw85/3/

**EDIT 2:**

Remove float: left in ul#nav, or just remove the id="nav" in the ul-tag in the html

Comment: That did not solve it, it made the drop down menu behave wierd. I tried both adding what you wrote and also only using those things under each tag, still no change. Also there wasn't no "ul.sf-menu li a" in the CSS so I added it, still didn't work.

Comment: Tried the code from your fiddle, still no change. The menu is still aligned to the left side. Viewed in Chrome 32.0 and Firefox 27.0.

Comment: But did it align center in the fiddle?

Comment: Yeah it looks centered in the fiddle. So how come it won't become centered when opening my index.html after copying your fiddle code to my style.css? For some reason it's still aligned to the left there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to center the menu you need to set the width of the child div to be smaller than a set width of a parent. Additionally need to remove the float of the menu as floating an element effectively takes it out of the parent div.

Try setting the following:

```
ul.sf-menu {
  float: none;
  width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Works when inspecting element. Another alternative would be to try the following code.

```
ul.sf-menu {
  float: none;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add:

```
ul#nav {
  float:left;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
```

Comment: @esser the site which walter provided was not responsive and if you still wanna center the div then you must provide some specific width to that div and assign style margin:auto; to that element

Comment: Okay, I don't follow links so I didn't see the website.

Comment: That did not center it.